# Firemonkey Hints don't work in Delphi Seattle, for a project converted from XE7

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, hint, delphi-10-seattle

I opened [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/FMX.MouseOverHints_Sample) demo in Delphi Seattle and it works like it should.
When I open my program, and include the demo form it doesnt work. I cannot add hints to my controls.

```
    procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      application.ShowHint:=true;
      application.OnHint :=OnApplicationHint;
    end;

    procedure TMainForm.OnApplicationHint(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      caption := (Application.Hint);
    end;

My program is converted from XE7 to Seattle. So what could be the difference?
```

Where can i find the code that actually shows the hint??

EDIT : I found the code that shows a Hint. The following works in a new XE-10 Seattle program, but not in a program converted from XE-7 .

```
var
  LToolInfo: TOOLINFO;

  FNativeControlHandle,
  FToolTipHandle: HWND;
begin
 FNativeControlHandle := WindowHandleToPlatform(form1.Handle).Wnd;
  if FNativeControlHandle <> 0 then begin
    FToolTipHandle := CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, nil, WS_POPUP or TTS_ALWAYSTIP, 0, 0, 300, 300,FNativeControlHandle, 0, hInstance, nil);


    SetWindowPos(FToolTipHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOACTIVATE);

    FillChar(LToolInfo, SizeOf(TOOLINFO), 0);
    LToolInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TOOLINFO);
    LToolInfo.uFlags := TTF_SUBCLASS or TTF_IDISHWND or TTF_PARSELINKS;
    LToolInfo.hinst := hInstance;
    LToolInfo.hwnd := FNativeControlHandle;
    LToolInfo.uId := FNativeControlHandle;
    LToolInfo.lpszText := PWideChar('Hint');


    SendMessage(FToolTipHandle, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, LPARAM(@LToolInfo));
    SendMessage(FToolTipHandle, TTM_ACTIVATE, NativeInt(True), LPARAM(@LToolInfo));
  end;
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? - I have the same problem.

Comment: No, I have layed this problem to rest for now. When i find a solution i will update this question.

Comment: I had a similar problem with the hints on XE8 converted to Berlin, which I solved by recreating the .dproj file. Not the most elegant solution, but it was quicker than searching through the .dproj for the reason. Another problem was that hints disappeared when changing the form's BorderIcons. After some debugging I found the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603480/hints-on-firemonkey-not-displaying-in-delphi-seattle/41623130#41623130

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with hints in a converted program from `XE7` not working in `Delphi Seattle`.

When I switched on the checkbox `"Activate runtime themes"` ("Laufzeit-Themes aktivieren" in my German version) (`Project --> Options --> Application`) the hints appeared!

Comment: Cannot confirm now, will test later!

Comment: I've tested this and it does seem to matter. When I create a new Seattle program and turn it off, the hints don't show. And it was turned of in my converted XE7 program. But when I turn it on, they still don't show. They do fire hints however