# Hints on Firemonkey not displaying in Delphi Seattle

Tags: user-interface, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

It is nice that Firemonkey got again the Hint property for controls, at least in Delphi Berlin and Seattle.
However, the implementation seems to be a bit flawed yet.

One weird issue is that the displaying of the `Hint` seems related to the form's `BorderIcons` property. If the `BorderIcons` are left with the default values (Maximize, Minimize, SystemMenu), the hint shows. But if I change some of the border icons, the hints don't show any more. I don't see any logic for it, so it looks like a bug. I traced some code in the `FMX.Forms` unit, but couldn't find any relation to the border icons. The hints in `TriggerControlHint` and other methods seem to be set correctly.

Has anyone had such an issue and have you solved it somehow?

There are other issue, like hints not working on a XE8 project converted to Seattle on Windows. It was mentioned in this question [Firemonkey Hints don't work in Delphi Seattle, for a project converted from XE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914667/firemonkey-hints-dont-work-in-delphi-seattle-for-a-project-converted-from-xe7). I fixed that by recreating the dproj file and it probably has something to do with the default manifests/themes.

Also hints for controls placed on a TLayout don't show, because the layout doesn't have the ShowHint property. Doesn't sound very logical to me, but at least it can be overcome by setting each control's ShowHint property manually.

The issue is reported on QC as [RSP-13218](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13218)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more tracing through `FMX.Forms` I found the bug.

In the end of the `TCommonCustomForm.Create` method the hint object is set with

```
if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
  FSharedHint := THint.CreateNewInstance(Handle);
```

but when the BorderIcons are changed, and also in other cases, it calls the TCommonCustomForm.Recreate method, which also recreates the window handle, so the hint is no longer linked to it.
To fix it I had to also recreate the hint by adding a few lines before the `finally` clause in the `Recreate` method:

```
if Visible and ([TFmxFormState.Showing] * FormState = []) then
  FWinService.ShowWindow(Self);
// Added lines
if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
begin
  FSharedHint.Free;
  FSharedHint := THint.CreateNewInstance(Handle);
end;
```

Comment: It is already reported, I saw at least one issue posted there. I wrote a comment with the solution in case someone looks at it.

Comment: Ah, ok. It would be great if you add a link to the QP on this SO question. This means that everyone having same issue will find it on QP and vote for it.